# LINQ Summary of Nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, nested

Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, double>>

```
2015/6/1 10:30  table1  300,
                table2  600

2015/6/1 11:25  table1  200

2015/6/2 10:25  table1  200,
                table2  700
```

How can i get these summary result

Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, double>>

```
2015/6/1   table1  500,
           table2  600

2015/6/2   table1  200,
           table2  700
```

Comment: How do you generate the output? Use .ToShortDateString() on the DateTime value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flatten your inner dictionary using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.95).aspx) after that you can apply [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.95).aspx) on DateTime first (`Key` in your dictionary) and in the result you need to again group by `tables`. Finally you can project your output as Dictionary. Here is the complete code:-

```
Dictionary<DateTime,Dictionary<string,double>> result = 
                      data.SelectMany(x => x.Value, (key, obj) => new { key, obj })
                          .GroupBy(x => new { Date = x.key.Key.Date })
                          .Select(x => new
          {
              Date = x.Key.Date,
              Output = x.GroupBy(z => z.obj.Key)
                 .Select(t => new { Table = t.Key, Sum = t.Sum(m => m.obj.Value) })
                 .ToDictionary(d => d.Table, d => d.Sum)
          }).ToDictionary(x => x.Date, x=> x.Output);
```

[Working Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uEPQrE)

Comment: thank you,that helps me a lot.  i'm new to linq and SelectMany will be the next subject to study.